# Docusign Custom tags - formula tags

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

We are using Conga Composer to generate and send docs to customer (background mode) by adding DocuSign custom tags as integration parameters in the API call. we would want to add 3 days to the date signed value dynamically but formula tag is not supported in custom tags [Documentation](https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-user-guide-advanced-sending-using-the-calculated-fields-feature). Any thoughts how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a formula tag with the formula `AddDays([DateSigned],3)`

Here is a sample [createEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) request.

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes

 {
     "emailSubject": "Please sign the agreement with two Date Tabs",
     "status": "sent",
     "recipients": {
         "signers": [
             {
                 "name": "Jane Doe",
                 "email": "JaneDoe@acme.com",
                 "recipientId": "1",
                 "tabs": {
                     "dateSignedTabs": [
                         {
                             "tabLabel": "ImportantDate",
                             "documentId": "1",
                             "pageNumber": "1",
                             "xPosition": "100",
                             "yPosition": "150"
                         }
                     ],
                     "formulaTabs": [
                         {
                             "formula": "AddDays( [ImportantDate],3)",
                             "width": "100",
                             "documentId": "1",
                             "pageNumber": "1",
                             "xPosition": "300",
                             "yPosition": "150"
                         }
                     ]
                 }
             }
         ]
     },
     "documents": [
         {
             "documentId": "1",
             "name": "Contract",
             "fileExtension": "txt",
             "documentBase64": "VGVzdCBEb2N1bWVudA=="
         }
     ]
 }
```

Comment: We are doing this through Conga Composer, no direct API call to DocuSign. [Conga - DocuSign](https://support.getconga.com/Conga_Composer/Customizing_Composer_with_Parameters/Composer_Parameter_Guide/DocuSign_Integration_Parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Docusign confirmed that this is not possible via anchor tags (custom tags).